# How can i deploy slim framework api on godaddy cplex server?

Tags: slim

I have deployed my slim api project folder on godaddy server but this is not working after uploading. How can i upload on godaddy server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can  I uploade my APi on Ipage hosting 
You just need to config Your apache server on Your hosting 
like this docs [Slim Web server configration](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html)

Note: Make sure you choose the correct Slim version when viewing the documentations.

Comment: I already tried for this but i didn't got the solution. If you know the correct solution for godaddy then please help me.